# open pdf with AS3 on AIR app

Tags: android, pdf, air

I'm making an AIR app for Android and I would like to open a pdf when the user click on a button.

I've got this code :

```
printBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, print, false, 0, true);

function print(event:MouseEvent):void{
var myPDF = new URLRequest("pdfs/all.pdf");
navigateToURL(myPDF);

}
```

I've include the folder "pdfs" on the publish settings.

When I try the app with the Flash CC simulator, it's working but when I test it on an Android device, nothing is happening when I click on the button. (the all.pdf won't open).

I've tried to change

```
var myPDF = new URLRequest("pdfs/all.pdf");
```

by

```
var myPDF = new URLRequest("http://www.mysite/all.pdf");
```

in order to test the function and it's working on the android device as it opens the pdf online when I click on the button.

Do you know why it doesn't open my pdf locally ? (I repeat, I've included the folder "pdfs" in my publish setting)

Thx for your help

Comment: Hey, Please check the edits in my answer, this should solve your problem. Please accept the answer if it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** After reading the question again and again, I think the problem is something else. I feel this is a application sandbox security issue, and I think that the browser app in your device cannot access the local files (all.pdf) residing in your app directory. I think you would need to write the file first in the **'documentsDirectory'** which should be publicly accessible to Android.

Look at this thread here and look at the accepted answer comments:

[how do I open a newly written file from application storage directory in as3 / flex mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25967947/how-do-i-open-a-newly-written-file-from-application-storage-directory-in-as3-f)

**My older anwser:**

Could be a relative URL issue. Check the path of your local PDF, and debug to see if its actually getting packaged or not.

Try "/pdfs/all.pdf" and see if that works.

Comment: I've check the path of my local PDF, no problem there. I've tried "/pdfs/all.pdf/" not working either...

Comment: I even tried to put my all.pdf directly into the root (not in a folder) and put "all.pdf" but it is not working either.

Comment: Are you able to physically verify the file exists on the device by using a file explorer? Also, do you get any error messages while accessing the PDF in a debug mode? Also, have you tried copying the file first into the applicationStorageDirectory and then accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

Within Flash CC, before you publish your app, make sure you are including the pdf in the Settings > General > Included Files area.